# How do I cook beetroot

Tags: culinary-uses, beets

I've just pulled some beetroot out of my garden.

I've never cooked beetroot before so would love a few suggestions.

Comment: And don't forget the leaves are spinach-like when boiled!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you boil them or roast them until tender, then let them cool and peel them. It is better not to cut or peel them before cooking, they will bleed lots of color and flavor. Some classic things to do with them: puree into a soup called borscht, slice them in a salad (particularly nice with goat cheese), serve as a roasted vegetable like you would a potato or turnip. They especially love dairy products with a little tang such as sour cream, feta cheese, yogurt and so forth.

Comment: We roast them and then dice and serve over warm pasta that's got some olive oil and goat cheese mixed in. If we have the greens, we'll saute them briefly and add them as well.

Comment: Heck yeah. And good point about the greens. Here is another use for them: http://www.herbivoracious.com/2008/03/recipe-beet-rec.html

Comment: (3 parts grated (boiled) beetroot to 1 part minced garlic to 1 part minced walnut) + mayonnaise = relish of win ;)

Comment: Also a very nice relish -> beetroot+horseradish

Answer (score 2):

I like them steamed: Steam , unpeeled, for around 35 minutes depending on size. Use paper towel to rub off the peel after it's cooked, and then slice.

They're very likely to stain your nice towels, clothing, and counter-tops .... a cutting board is recommended.

Comment: I'll second being VERY careful with the juice. Definitely a big stain maker. Wear an apron.

Answer (score 2):

My Russian Flatmate inspired me to try 'beetroot chocolate cake'. The beetroot keeps the cake really moist but without the need to use much butter/oil. It's really healthy and tastes very rich and moist, almost similar to chocolate browny. I made two of them in the last couple of weeks and will make another one tomorrow.
As per recipe, I tend to change mine over time, but as a rough guideline, you can use a carrot cake recipe and replace the carrots with beetroot. And of course add some chocolate :). My cakes both had about 1/2 kg of beetroot in it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way i have beets is roasted with a little olive oil, salt and pepper(fresh cracked of course).  I find that if steamed or boiled, the beet flavor gets watered down. Sometimes i make a relish like dish with with the baked beets sliced along with parsely, garlic,onions, and a light drizzle of white vinegar,  letting it macerate for a few hours before eating.